# How to properly align rows with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am making a basic website and having a problem with aligning rows with columns. I have a few rows and it seems like because of the gutters they are pushed to one side. How can I make it so that the body is lined up together? i've attached code and a picture to show what's happening.[image]

```css
    .nav3{

 

 ul{
  
   background-color:orange;
   overflow:auto;

   .red{
    color:$red;
   }

   .blue{
    color:$blue;
   }

   .green{
    color:$green;
   }

   .pink{
    color:$pink;
   }
  


   li{
    font-size: 1.4em;
    float:left;
    list-style-type: none;

    


   }

   li:last-child{
    border:0px;
   }

   p{
    margin:0;
   }
  
 }
}

    footer{
    
     [class*="zocial-"]{
      color:orange;
      font-size:2em;
     }
    
      background-color: $greyHeader;



  

    .list1{
       list-style-type: none;
       li{
        float:left;
       }
    
    
      }
    
      .list2{
       list-style-type: none;
       li{
        float:left;
       }
      }
    
      .list3{
       list-style-type: none;
      }
    }

    .row1Pics{

 height:300px;

 p{
  font-size:1.5em;
  color:white;
  padding:1em;
 }

 .grey{
  background-color:grey;
  max-width:100%;
  
 }

 button{
 padding:1.1em;
 border: 3px solid green;
 background-color:white;
 font-size:1.4em;
 margin-bottom:1.2em;

 }
    }


    .row2Pics{
     .col-md-4{
      background-color:grey;
     }
 
 

 button{
  padding:1.1em;
  border:3px solid blue;
  background-color:white;
  font-size:1.4em;
  margin-bottom:1.2em;
 }

 p{
  color:white;
  font-size:1.4em;
  padding:1em;
 }

    }
```

```html
    <link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <div class="row nav2">
 <div class="col-md-12">
  <p class=" heading text-right">
   Need help? Call our 24 hr hotline
  </p>
  <p class="text-right number">
   328-0922
  </p>
 </div>
</div>


    <div class="row nav3">
     <ul>
      <li class="col-md-3 red text-center">I need <br> Help</li>
      <li class="col-md-3 blue text-center">I need <br> Information</li>
      <li class="col-md-3 green text-center">I want <br> to donate</li>
      <li class="col-md-3 pink text-center">I want <br> to volunteer</li>
     </ul>
    
    </div>

    <!-- Carousel Start -->
    
    <div ng-controller="carouselController">
      <div style="height: 405px">
        <uib-carousel interval="myInterval" no-wrap="noWrapSlides">
          <uib-slide ng-repeat="slide in slides" active="slide.active" index="slide.id">
            <img ng-src="{{slide.image}}" style="margin:auto;">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h4>Slide {{slide.id}}</h4>
              <p>{{slide.text}}</p>
            </div>
          </uib-slide>
        </uib-carousel>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <!-- Carousel End -->




    <div class="row row1Pics ">
    
     <div class="col-md-8">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/780/300/sports">
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-4 grey">
      <p class="text-center">
       In order to offer help, we need your help. Consider becoming a partner
       with us against Violence in the Bahamas.
      </p>
      <button class="text-uppercase center-block">Donate Today</button>
     </div>
    
    </div>

    <div class="row row2Pics">
    
     <div class="col-md-4">
      <p class="text-center">
       Knowledge is power. Get information about Domestic Violence and abuse
       to how you can help youself or someone else.
      </p>
      <button class="text-uppercase center-block">Go To Resources</button>
     </div>
 <div class="col-md-8">
  <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/780/300/business">
 </div>

</div>

    <footer class="row">
     <ul class="col-md-4 list1">
      <li class="col-md-4">Donate</li>
      <li class="col-md-4">Volunteer</li>
      <li class="col-md-4">Contact Us</li>
     </ul>
    
     <ul class="col-md-5 list2">
      <li class="col-md-3 zocial-twitter"></li>
      <li class="col-md-3 zocial-pinterest"></li>
      <li class="col-md-3 zocial-youtube"></li>
      <li class="col-md-3 zocial-instagram"></li>
     </ul>
    
     <ul class="col-md-3 list3">
      <li>Bahamas Crisis Center</li>
      <li> P.O Box 44370</li>
      <li>Nassau, Bahamas</li>
     </ul>
    </footer>
```

http://codepen.io/mroker/pen/bpeQWv?editors=1100

Comment: The code that you gave is not enough

Comment: i just added all of the code for that page.

Comment: It would be better if you create a snippet with html and css code

Comment: may i ask how you create a snippet?

Comment: Using codepen.io or jsfiddle just paste the code accordingly

Comment: http://codepen.io/mroker/pen/bpeQWv?editors=1100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your columns are actually lined up, the reason they "look" unaligned is because as standard Bootstrap columns come with a left & right padding of 15px.

Which means when you apply `background-color: grey` onto a column it ignores the padding.

I made a little example for you here:
[Bootstrap Columns padding example](http://codepen.io/jtotty/pen/eZzxBy?editors=1100)

Comment: ok thanks so much for this explanation. Makes sense. So how would I get the grey to come all of the way out to the side?

Comment: @arsenalist You can either apply the background on the column like you did in your example, or remove the padding on the column.

Answer (score 0):

So you are using Bootstrap, I assume that fact.
To align all of your elements, always place it inside the `col-md-`with the number of column you want, remember to fill all the 12 columns so it would be aligned automatically.

I saw you are missing the `col-md-` for your carousel. Put it and check again!

Comment: when i put that on carousel it causes other rows to overlap unfortunately. But it may be a problem with the carousel I'm thinking.

Comment: also, all of my rows are inside of a row and every div or element is inside of a col.